# ActiveMQ ProtocolException Invalid CONNECT encoding

Tags: warnings, activemq-classic, mqtt, protocolexception

What means this warning in ActiveMQ?

```
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx failed: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid CONNECT encoding
```

I use ActiveMQ as broker and connect from Android with MQTT. I get every connect this warning in ActiveMQ console.

Answer (score 0):

The error would indicate something is wrong with your CONNECT frame, some MQTT spec violation.  It's hard to say without more info on the error.  Things like clean session not being set when the clientId value is zero length etc can lead to protocol level errors.

You can enable more logs from MQTT in your log4j.properties using something like:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt=TRACE
```